# Decode from base64 and execute command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, base64

I want to execute command on Linux box, but I should send commands on base64 format.

How can I decode base64 string on Linux command and then execute the decoded string?

Comment: mine has `base64` installed as command, otherwise if you have openssl, it can also decode `openssl base64 -d` : try e.g. 

`$( echo 'ZWNobyBhYmMK' | openssl base64 -d )` **Note** If you have no control about the base64, be careful, it might contain rm -rf ~ or other neat stuff

Comment: @Stefan You experienced bad moments with base64 in particular ?

Comment: Nope, but encoutered systems like AIX servers where openssl was there already but base64 wasn't. Just using what I found to be usable and got used to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `base64 -d`:

```
# 'string' variable contains a base64 encoded command
command=$(base64 -d <<< "$string"); decode_status=$?
# run the command only if decode was successful
# we shouldn't enclose $command in double quotes in this case
[[ $decode_status == 0 ]] && $command
```